# authentication error for mifare card "6982:Security status not satisfied"

Tags: authentication, command, smartcard, mifare

I have pc/sc reader and Contactless card(mifare card), I can connect to the card and also I execute getdate command successfully, but when I want to authenticate I see this error "6982:Security status not satisfied"
I've tried these 3 different commands for authentication but I get the same error for all of them.

```
FF 88 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF 88 00 00 60 12
FF 88 00 00 05 01 00 12 60 00
```

how can I fix this error?what is my mistake?

Comment: I've find the answer ,I use this command and it's worked<ff 88 00 00 60 00>

Comment: You can post answers to your own questions and accept them (after a while) helia, that way they can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've find the answer ,I used this command and it worked`<ff 88 00 00 60 00>`